# MongoDB: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date

Tags: ruby, mongodb, aggregation-framework, database, nosql

I' trying to use aggregation framework (with ruby) and project the date  like this:

```
db['requests'].aggregate([
{"$project" => {
    _id: 0, 
    method: '$method', 
    user: '$user', 
    year: {'$year' => '$timestamp'}
}}])
```

the document is like this one:

```
{
_id: ObjectId("5177d7d7df26358289da7dfd"),
timestamp: ISODate("2013-04-12T03:58:05+00:00"),
method: "POST",
status: "200",
inputsize: "874",
outputsize: "4981",
user: "131"
}
```

but i get the following error:

```
Mongo::OperationFailure: Database command 'aggregate' failed: (errmsg: 'exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date'; code: '16006'; ok: '0.0').
```

This is strange because it works correctly if I run this on the exactly same db which is imported with mongorestore.

Comment: Apparently the order of the array passed in to aggregate() is important.  If you have fields where something is omitted, you'll want to add that into the $match and have the $match be the first element in the array. I.e.   > db.user_account.aggregate( [ { $match : { "uts" : { $exists : true }, "chan_key" : "333261c7a72650a95c68d30cd70" } } , { $project : { "period_month": { $month: "$uts" } } }, { $group: { _id : { "period_month" : "$period_month" }, "number" : { $sum : 1 } } } ]  )

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem was that I was saving some documents without the timestamp field.

Comment: Yup! Me too. I did a search for documents where my timestamp was 'nil' and there was just one document. I fixed that, and voila! the query works.

Comment: Can you put up an example of how you found such documents.

Answer (score 2):

If you needed to have some documents without this timestamp field, you could try this (I'm using Javascript/Mongoose notation):

```
year: { $cond: [{ $ifNull: ['$timestamp', 0] }, { $year: '$deliveryDateEnd' }, -1] }
```

In this case, every document without the timestamp field would return -1. All the other documents would return the year as expected.