# Aggregation on datetime

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to aggregate using group on datetime value on below collection,

```
{
    "_id" : 104801,
    "requests" : {
        "rstTimeStamp" : ISODate("2014-11-11T10:30:13.577Z"),
        "emailId" : "user1@example.com"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : 104802,
    "requests" : {
        "rstTimeStamp" : ISODate("2014-11-11T12:40:13.577Z"),
        "emailId" : "user2@example.com"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : 104803,
    "requests" : {
        "rstTimeStamp" : ISODate("2014-11-12T12:40:13.577Z"),
        "emailId" : "user3@example.com"
    }
}
```

And expecting the output to show total number of requests for particular date for e.g. date 2014-11-11 has 2 requests. But due to the time value in the date it is considering every date as a single document.

Any help on this will be appreciated.

EDIT: My query is as follows:

```
db.clrequests.aggregate({ $group : { _id : "$requests.rstTimeStamp", total : {$sum : 1} } })
```

Comment: Could you post the aggregation query you have created?

Comment: Here is my query,                                                     db.clrequests.aggregate({
    $group : {
             _id : "$requests.rstTimeStamp",
             total : {$sum : 1}             
            }
   })

Comment: In above duplicate link follow that aggregate code and add `$project` after group like this `{"$project":{"_id":{"$add": [new Date(0), "$_id"]},"count":1}}` it will return you expected output

Comment: Thank you @Yogesh I solved using query "db.clrequests.aggregate([
{
  $match:{"requests":{$exists:true}}  
},
{
    $group: {
             _id:{ $substr: [ "$requests.rstTimeStamp", 0, 10 ] },
             total : {$sum : 1}  
         }
},
{ $sort : { _id: 1 } }
])"

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [Date Aggregaetion](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) operator for this :

Please check the below query :

```
db.exp8.aggregate([ 
                    { $group : 
                      { _id: 
                        { year : {$year:"$requests.rstTimeStamp"},
                          month: {$month:"$requests.rstTimeStamp"},
                          day :  {$dayOfMonth:"$requests.rstTimeStamp"}
                        },
                        Total : { $sum : 1 } , 
                        dte : {$first:"$requests.rstTimeStamp"} 
                       }
                     },
                     { $project : { _id : "$dte" , Total : 1 } } 
                   ]);
```

OutPut :

```
{ "_id" : ISODate("2014-11-12T12:40:13.577Z"), "Total" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ISODate("2014-11-11T10:30:13.577Z"), "Total" : 2 }
```

Comment: I got a error saying "uncaught exception: aggregate failed: {
 "errmsg" : "exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date",
 "code" : 16006,
 "ok" : 0
}"

Comment: You mite have one or more docs with a "requests.rstTimeStamp" value that's not a BSON Date. There is a sloution in the below Stack overflow link for that error, Please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415995/exception-cant-convert-from-bson-type-eoo-to-date

Comment: I'm expecting the output as {
            "_id" : ISODate("2014-11-11"),
            "total" : 2.0000000000000000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ISODate("2014-11-12"),
            "total" : 1.0000000000000000
        }

Comment: check now, i have modiofied the solution as per your needs.