# can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date - Works with mongodb but get this error with pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I have the following code.

```
collection.aggregate( [
        { "$project": {
            "Coordinates": 1,
            "Time": 1, 
            "Name": 1,
            "minutes": { "$add": [
                { "$multiply": [ { "$hour": '$Time' }, 60 ] }, 
                { "$minute": '$Time' } 
            ] } 
        } },
        { "$match": { 'minutes' : { "$gt" : 00 * 60, "$lt" : 6 * 60 } } },
        {"$group":{"_id": { "Name":"$Name","Coordinates":'$Coordinates' },
           "Sum": { "$sum": 1} }},
        {"$group":{"_id":"$_id.Name","LatLong": { 
                       "$push": { 
                           "Coordinates": "$_id.Coordinates",
                           "Count" : "$Sum"
                       }}
        }},
        {"$project": { "Name":"$_id","_id":0,"LatLong": 1}}
] )
```

This is how a document looks.

```
{
    _id" : "f865554a-e3c1-497a-a0a3-c261ee75b917", 
    "Name" : "Sam", 
    "Time" : ISODate("2016-01-01T01:50:26.420+0000"), 
    "Coordinates" : [
        13.9830857, 
        49.7341339
    ]
}
```

I am getting the error below

> can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date

What is type EOO, and why am I getting this error?
I did the following check:

```
db.collection.count({"Time":{$type:9}})
```

all of them were of type Date. (by checking that number was equal to the total number of documents.)

EDIT:**There is one more thing that I've realized. If I run the same query on mongodb, it runs successfully. Then why does it give me this error when I run it in pymongo? I am running MongoDB version 3.0.12 and python version 2.7.10.**

Comment: Your count query should be `count({"Time":{$type:9}})` because the field `Time` is the field your aggregation is using.

Comment: @AminJ Yup. Edited it. That's what I did!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28416864/3271558

Comment: @SteveRossiter, I've already made that check as mentioned in my question.

Comment: can you confirm the pymongo and mongodb versions please?

Comment: Check edits please.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot replicate this error. You may want to try providing a complete example that includes the document insert and then aggregation in one script.