# MongoError: can't convert from BSON type missing to Date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using `mongoose 4.5.0` and trying to fetch data using aggregation but it fails.

Here is my node code:-

```
    ..
    var preMonths = new moment().subtract(4, 'months').date(1).toDate();     //4:for 5 month
    var match = { $and: [] };
    match.$and.push({ companyId: new ObjectID(req.user.companyId._id) });
    match.$and.push({ status: 'CONVERTED' });


    var allUnderUsers = [];
    req.session.underUser.forEach(function(element, index) {
        allUnderUsers.push(ObjectID(element))
    });
    match.$and.push({ assignTo: { $in: allUnderUsers } });

    match.$and.push({ createdOn: { $gt: preMonths, $lt: new moment().toDate() } });
    var aggregate = [
        { $match: match }, {
            $group: {
                _id: { month: { $month: "$date" },year: { $year: "$date" } },
                total: { $sum: '$value' }
            }
        }
    ];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(aggregate))
    Lead.aggregate(aggregate)
        .exec(function(err, data) {
            if (err)
                return next(err)
            var temp = [];
            data.forEach(function(element, index) {
                temp.push([moment().month(element._id.month).format('MMM')+' '+element._id.year, element.total]);
            })
            res.status(200).json(temp)
        })
   ..
```

here is query string after consoling :-

> >
>   console.log(aggreate)
>
> ---
>
> >
>   [{"$match":{"$and":[{"companyId":"5875bb5ba5a2f0e52f76ec6c"},{"status":"CONVERTED"},{"assignTo":{"$in":["587dbf58cab7be105d076516","587dcd3edca5f235f862fdfd","587e1002dca5f235f862fe03","587e1079ad90f640757d396a","587e1193af725041b6a41a4d","587e131faf725041b6a41a58","587f1705edf2fa25f0ed1935","5881a1ffc51165fbc30a2c60","58873cb9ca352ccf80337ccd"]}},{"createdOn":{"$gt":"2016-10-01T09:11:19.357Z","$lt":"2017-02-01T09:11:19.358Z"}}]}},{"$group":{"_id":{"month":{"$month":"$date"},"year":{"$year":"$date"}},"total":{"$sum":"$value"}}}]

Now, here error:-

> { MongoError: can't convert from BSON type missing to Date
>       at Function.MongoError.create (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11) at
>   Socket.
>   (/home/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:306:22)
>       at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:172:18)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:130:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:542:20)   name: 'MongoError',   message: 'can\'t convert from BSON type missing to Date',   ok: 0,   errmsg:
>   'can\'t convert from BSON type missing to Date',   code: 16006,
>   codeName: 'Location16006' }

Comment: From the error " 'can\'t convert from BSON type missing to Date'"
, Can you make sure the date value is not null

Comment: yes, date value not null here is date query log `"createdOn":{"$gt":"2016-10-01T09:11:19.357Z","$lt":"2017-02-01T09:11:19.358Z"}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [exception: can't convert from BSON type EOO to Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415995/exception-cant-convert-from-bson-type-eoo-to-date)

Comment: Add another match condition to ensure all fields you expect to be of Date class are actually Dates.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to use Mongo date operations (e.g. `$year`, `$month`, `$day`) on a field which is not a date.

The problem is with this part of your query:

```
_id: {
  month: { $month: "$date" },
  year: { $year: "$date" }
},
```

Possibly some or all of your documents have no value in the `date` field.

(As you said, it was a typo, and your field had a different name!)

A similar problem was discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28415995/exception-cant-convert-from-bson-type-eoo-to-date), where the value of the field was present, but not of type date.

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to use the `$month` operator on a String.

The problem is here:

```
 month: { $month: "$date" }
```

Your date field is something like: `"2017-02-01T09:11:19.358Z"`

which is a String and `year: { $year: "$date" }` this will work on that date string. But month is not. You have to convert the expression as follows:

```
{ $month: ISODate("2017-02-01T09:11:19.358Z") } ie 
{ $month: ISODate("$date") }
```

Will solve the issue.

Check more about month aggregator: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/month/