# Find non-ISODate records in MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I have a Mongo collection that stored a date field as a string. I ran the query below to convert this field into an ISODate, but it failed. However, there are quite a few records that now show as an ISODate.

How do I query to find all documents that are an ISODate format and all documents that are still a string?

```
db.TestCollection.find({}).forEach(function(doc) {
    doc.LastUpdated = new Date(doc.LastUpdated );

    db.TestCollection.save(doc);

    });
```

The original question has been answered, but the follow up question is: Is there a way to aggregate the type of data present in the column? I would like to return a count of each type of data in the column. I have seen type string and type date, but want to verify there isn't any other data types.

Here's roughly what I have tried:

```
db.TestCollection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
       LastUpdated : { $type: "$LastUpdated " }
    }
}])
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/28416864/1259510

Comment: You are a life saver. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to aggregate them on which type? So it shows I have 100 of type String, 200 of type Date, etc.?

Comment: Something like `db.TestCollection.aggregate([{
    "$group": {"_id":{"$type": "$LastUpdated"}, "count":{"$sum":1}}
    }
])`