# MongoDB! query to get data from specific date of different format

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new in mongoDB, please help me for below question description:

I have collection `xyz` having one of column `insertDate` having date of `dd/mm/YYYY` format. I want all records from xyz collection whose `insertDate` is greater than `28/01/2022`.

I try below query and it return correct data but return only insertDate column but i want whole json record with above condition:

`db.xyz.aggregate([{ $project: { insertDate: { $dateFromString: { format: '%d/%m/%Y', dateString: '$insertDate' } } } }, { $match: { insertDate: { '$gt': new Date("2022-01-01") } } } ]);`

Please help me in this problem.

Comment: Storing date as string is generally considered as anti-pattern. Nevertheless, have you checked out [$dateFromString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)?

Comment: @ray Yes i use that one also. Can u provide me full query for that?

Comment: Can you share your current attempt, what is the error you are having, and some sample documents?

Comment: @ray I use below command also: `db.claims.aggregate([{ $addFields: { insertDate: { $dateToString: { format: '%Y-%m-%d', date: '$insertDate' } } } }, { $match: { insertDate: { '$gt': new Date("2022-01-01") } } } ]);`

Comment: @ray  I used below for dateFromString:  `db.xyz.aggregate([{ $project: { insertDate: { $dateFromString: { format: '%d/%m/%Y', dateString: '$insertDate' } } } } ]);` and it returns useless data like: `{ "_id" : ObjectId("5fc1109ae8288600013b1941"), "insertDate" : ISODate("2020-11-27T05:30:00.000+05:30") }`

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Instead, update your questions with the new info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to convert your date in your database from a string to a date, and then filter it. You can do this with the aggregation pipeline.

> ⚠️ Warning: This can become very inefficient if you're working with large data as it requires a whole collection scan to covert each date so you won't be able to utilize indexes.

Let's start with some data:

```js
db.test.insertMany([
   { insertDate: "02/05/2021" },
   { insertDate: "02/05/2019" },
   { insertDate: "02/05/2023" },
   { insertDate: "02/05/2022" },
   { insertDate: "02/05/2025" },
]);
```

Once we've inserted these documents we can query it using an aggregation query:

```js
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "insertDate": {
                "$dateFromString": {
                    "dateString": "$insertDate",
                    "format": "%d/%m/%Y"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "insertDate": {
                "$gt": ISODate("2022-01-28T00:00:00Z")
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Then we'll get the following results:

```js
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62baec6a6fd118e327dc7ded"), "insertDate" : ISODate("2023-05-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62baec6a6fd118e327dc7dee"), "insertDate" : ISODate("2022-05-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("62baec6a6fd118e327dc7def"), "insertDate" : ISODate("2025-05-02T00:00:00Z") }
```

For more information research the [$dateFromString](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/) function and also the [aggregation pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/)

Comment: Thanks for answer but i want to return whole json record not only insertDate column.

Comment: @ankit This will return the whole record and not project any columns.

Comment: ok got it thnx kevin

Answer (score 0):

Below query help me:

```
db.xyz.aggregate([{ $project: { insertDate: { $dateFromString: { format: '%d/%m/%Y', dateString: '$insertDate' } },claimNo: 1 } }, { $match: { insertDate: { '$gt': new Date("2022-01-01") } } } ]);
```

Where it returns:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("61d25493fc1f7b20de3c970e"),
"claimNo" : "03CL01",
"insertDate" : ISODate("2022-01-03T05:30:00.000+05:30")}
```

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72786002/6097074